# Firebase Create User with email and password gives me string must be unwrapped error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
    // ...
    guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
}
```

I copied and pasted the line from Firebase and got stuck with these errors.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUeBE.png)

Comment: can you provide details about your `email` and `password` variables that you pass to the method? are those optional strings?

Comment: both email and password are the text of the appropriate textfields

Comment: There's a great answer from @jeremiah and it would probably help if we knew how email and password were getting assigned i.e. include that code i your question. As stated in the answer, if they are the strings from UITextField then they are by default optionals [See UITextField.text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) and should be safely unwrapped before using them to ensure you are not passing nil to createUser.

Answer (score 3):

Those errors are caused by your email and password being optional (String? vs String). You need to unwrap them before passing them in to `createUser`. You can add the line `guard let email = email, let password = password else { return }` before making the call to remove the errors. Then depending on how you are getting the values, you'll probably want to show a user message if they are null.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremiah is correct.  You are trying to pass "optional" strings into the Firebase function.

Optional meaning that it could have a **value** or it could be **nil**.  You can unwrap those two Strings (email and password) a couple different ways:

```
    guard let email = email?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).lowercased(),
        !emailAddress.isEmpty else {
            // Uh oh email address is empty!  Show an error.
            return
    }

    guard let password = password, !password.isEmpty else {
        // Uh oh password is empty!  Show an error.
        return
    }
    login(with: emailAddress, password: password)
```

***Or:***

```
    if let email = email?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).lowercased(),
        let password = password, !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty {
        // Both email and password have values, do stuff:
    login(with: emailAddress, password: password)
            return
    } else {
        // Either email or password are empty, show an error
        return
    }

/// Asks Firebase to login our user.
private func login(with email: String, password: String) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error, !error.isEmpty {
            // Error signing in!
        }

    }
}
```